# Why __doPostBack doesn't work properly？

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a page with a link for exit.(when user click the exit, clear all session).

```
<body>
 <form runat="server">
  <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
   <ul class="menu">
     <li><a href="Default.aspx">صفحه اصلی</a></li>
     <li><a id="register" href="Register.aspx">ثبت نام</a></li>
     <li ><a id="login" href="#">ورود</a></li>
     <li><a href="ContactUs.aspx">تماس با ما</a></li>
     <li><a href="About.aspx">درباره ما</a></li>
     <li><a id="exit" href="javascript:ClearSession();" style="display: none">خروج</a>
     </li>
     <li style="position: absolute; border: none; left: 0"><a style="border: none; font-size: 12px" id="defalutpage" ><span id="WelcomUser" /></a></li>
   </ul>
```

and use javascript in head tag

```
 function ClearSession() {
  __doPostBack('__Page', 'ClearSession');
 };
```

and in code behind

```
 if (IsPostBack)
    {
        string _eventArg = Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"];
        if (_eventArg == "ClearSession")
        {
            Session.Clear();
        }
    }
```

but don't PostBack.

Comment: I use this article http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/1521-How-to-call-Postback-from-Javascript.aspx

Comment: "Don't PostBack" seems to be just as broad and unspecific as the famous "it doesn't work". [Try asking a decent question!](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The javascript function shoud be included between `<script>` tags.

Comment: I use it in `<script>`

Comment: I tried your code after putting the javascript function between <script> tags and it's posting back correctly with the "ClearSession" argument.

Comment: No, I use this in another page, it is work, but don't fire post back in my page :(

Comment: unfortunately it's working for me so I still don't know what problem are you facing, but if it's working in another page, then sure there's something you're missing with this page. I suggest that you do exactly everything you did in the other page and check step by step in order to find the error.